# Numpy applying operation on each element of matrix for each element of matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Title might be a little bit confusing. I want to do this:

```
output = []
x = np.asarray([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
y = np.asarray([[5,6,7],[7,8,9]])
for i in x:
    output.append(np.linalg.norm(i-y, axis = 0))
```

However, my x, y are very large so I need to speed it up by applying more vectorization. Any suggestions?

The expected output doesn't necessarily need to be a list. Anything that stores the info is fine.

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: @yatu I've udpated

Comment: Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract `y` broadcasted from `i` and take the frobernius from the resulting array as you where doing:

```
np.linalg.norm((x - y[:,None]), axis=0)

array([[7.21110255, 7.21110255, 7.21110255],
       [5.83095189, 5.83095189, 5.83095189]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you  also know how to do it for axis = 1?

Comment: Set axis to 1? @Goldname

Comment: I gave that a try but the results didn't seem right. Should there be an alteration of y's broadcasting?

Comment: not sure. But that should really be a separate question. I kindly encourage to ask another question for this, and accept this answer which solved the asked question. Otherwise it could also confuse future readers. @Goldname

Comment: Thanks for the response. I also want to do the following:
    output.append(np.linalg.norm(i-y, axis = 1))

Comment: However I cannot figure out how to adapt your solution to it. Do you have an idea?